# Some detail needed in Positive Definite Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

First all of all, I am sorry I have put a page of my text book. Somehow I need some help to understand some paragraphs in the page. If you can explain, please let me have some explanations to those in the image.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: For the first: it *says* that we define $y_i= x'e_i$

Comment: The second: try to show that $x=E'y$, then note $E$ is orthogonal (unitary).

Comment: For the last: we can always write $$ Q(x) = \sum \lambda_i y_i^2 $$

Comment: Let me know if you want further clarification

Comment: I read the page and kind of understand steps of calculations, but don't really understand what I need to understand from the context of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what there is to explain about 1 and 3.  I will say that the second equation follows by block-matrix multiplication:
$$
\pmatrix{e_1'\\e_2'} \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2} = 
\pmatrix{e_1'\\e_2'} (x) = 
\pmatrix{e_1'x\\e_2'x}= \pmatrix{y_1\\y_2}
$$